# PathCanonicalize equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, filenames

What is the equivalent to [PathCanonicalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773569(VS.85).aspx) in C#?

Use: I need to take a good guess whether two file paths refer to the same file (without disk access). My typical approach has been throwing it through a few filters like MakeAbsolute and PathCanonicalize, and then do a case-insensitive comparison.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**quick and dirty:**

In the past I have created a [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) object from the path string and then used the FullName property.  This removes all of the ..\'s and the .\'s.

Of course you could interop:

```
 [DllImport("shlwapi", EntryPoint="PathCanonicalize")]
    private static extern bool PathCanonicalize(
        StringBuilder lpszDst,
        string lpszSrc
    );
```

Answer (score 6):

3 solutions:

Best case scenario, where you are 100% certain the calling process will have full access to the filesystem.  **CAVEAT:** permission on a production box can be tricky

```
    public static string PathCombineAndCanonicalize1(string path1, string path2)
    {
        string combined = Path.Combine(path1, path2);
        combined = Path.GetFullPath(combined);
        return combined;
    }
```

But, we're not always free.  Often you need to do the string arithmetic without permission.  There is a native call for this.   **CAVEAT:** resorts to native call

```
    public static string PathCombineAndCanonicalize2(string path1, string path2)
    {
        string combined = Path.Combine(path1, path2);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(Math.Max(260, 2 * combined.Length));
        PathCanonicalize(sb, combined);
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool PathCanonicalize([Out] StringBuilder dst, string src);
```

A third strategy is to trick the CLR.  Path.GetFullPath() works just fine on a fictitious path, so just make sure you're always giving it one.  What you can do is to swap out the root with a phony UNC path, call GetFullPath(), and then swap the real one back in.  **CAVEAT:** this may require a hard sell in code review

```
    public static string PathCombineAndCanonicalize3(string path1, string path2)
    {
        string originalRoot = string.Empty;

        if (Path.IsPathRooted(path1))
        {
            originalRoot = Path.GetPathRoot(path1);
            path1 = path1.Substring(originalRoot.Length);
        }

        string fakeRoot = @"\\thiscantbe\real\";
        string combined = Path.Combine(fakeRoot, path1, path2);
        combined = Path.GetFullPath(combined);
        combined = combined.Substring(fakeRoot.Length);
        combined = Path.Combine(originalRoot, combined);
        return combined;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Path.GetFullPath()` does not work with relative paths. I've been looking for a solution that works for relative paths as well.

I tried many methods but none of them worked. @Paul's third strategy does not work with linux `\\` and has a bug with relative paths as it introduces one more folder, you lose one `..` in the result.

Here's the solution that works with both relative + absolute paths. It works on both Linux + Windows and it keeps the `..` as expected in the beginning of the text (at rest they will be normalized). The solution still relies on `Path.GetFullPath` to do the fix with a small workaround.

It's an extension method so use it like `text.Canonicalize()`

```
/// <summary>
///     Fixes "../.." etc
/// </summary>
public static string Canonicalize(this string path)
{
    if (path.IsAbsolutePath())
        return Path.GetFullPath(path);
    var fakeRoot = Environment.CurrentDirectory; // Gives us a cross platform full path
    var combined = Path.Combine(fakeRoot, path);
    combined = Path.GetFullPath(combined);
    return combined.RelativeTo(fakeRoot);
}
private static bool IsAbsolutePath(this string path)
{
    if (path == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(path));
    return
        Path.IsPathRooted(path)
        && !Path.GetPathRoot(path).Equals(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), StringComparison.Ordinal)
        && !Path.GetPathRoot(path).Equals(Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), StringComparison.Ordinal);
}
private static string RelativeTo(this string filespec, string folder)
{
    var pathUri = new Uri(filespec);
    // Folders must end in a slash
    if (!folder.EndsWith(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString())) folder += Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
    var folderUri = new Uri(folder);
    return Uri.UnescapeDataString(folderUri.MakeRelativeUri(pathUri).ToString()
        .Replace('/', Path.DirectorySeparatorChar));
}
```