# Convert Relative Path to Absolute Path

Tags: c#, relative-path, absolute-path

I am trying to open a Help.txt file in windows Forms using a linkLabel. However unable to convert from absolute to relative path.

First, I try to get the absolute path of the exe file. Which is successful.
Second, get only directory of the exe file. Which is successful.
Third, I am trying to combine the directory with the relative path of the Help.txt file. Which is unsuccessful.

Exe file lives in -> \Project\bin\Debug folder, However the Help.txt file lives in \Project\Help folder. This is my code:-

```
 string exeFile = (new System.Uri(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase)).AbsolutePath;
 string Dir = Uri.UnescapeDataString(Path.GetDirectoryName(exeFile));
 string path = Path.Combine(Dir, @"..\..\Help\Help.txt");
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
```

The result of my path is -> \Project\bin\Debug....\Help\Help.txt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PathCanonicalize equivalent in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623333/pathcanonicalize-equivalent-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Or perhaps see [path combine absolute with relative path strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670566/path-combine-absolute-with-relative-path-strings)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use Path.GetFullPath() to have the upper directory "../../" taken into account, see below :

```
string exeFile = new System.Uri(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase).AbsolutePath;
string Dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(exeFile);
string path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Dir, @"..\..\Help\Help.txt"));
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
```

Per the MSDN of [GetFullPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath(v=vs.113).aspx) : Returns the absolute path for the specified path string.
Whereas [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) Combines strings into a path.

Comment: Can you show us the value of path (with the invalid characters) ? and what is the value of exeFile as well ?

Comment: Uri.UnescapeDataString