# System.UnauthorizedAccessException in File.Create c#

Tags: c#, file, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

Edit: I noticed this doesn't happen when I just do: `File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\(usr)\Documents\Test\Data\test.txt", "0");` without `Globals.dmp` so evidently it must be something with `Path.Combine()` I tried various variations of the composition but with same results.
I want to create a folder and a text file in my c# program made with Visual Studio. What I'm doing is having a check at Form Load to see if the file exists, and if it does not, create the file. 
I'm doing it like this:

```
if(!File.Exists(Globals.dmp))
            {
                File.Create(Globals.dmp);
                File.WriteAllText(Globals.dmp, "0");
            }
```

The composition of `globals.dmp` is the following:

```
public static string dmp = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), Constants.dmp);
```

While `Constants.dmp` is like this:

```
public static string dmp = @"Test\Data\test.txt
```

This should work, but when I try to run it, Visual studio reports: `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\Users\(usr)\Documents\Test\Data\test.txt' is denied.'`The line that fails is: `File.Create(Globals.dmp);`
I tried putting `File.SetAttributes(Globals.dmp, new FileInfo(Globals.dmp).Attributes | FileAttributes.Normal);` above `File.Create` but the same thing happens. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using UWP?

Comment: @ekke I'm using visual studio with the latest .net and windowsform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by adapting `PathCombineAndCanonicalize1()` [from the second solution in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623333/pathcanonicalize-equivalent-in-c-sharp)

What I did is:

```
            public static string PathCombineAndCanonicalize1(string path1, string path2)
            { 
                string combined = Path.Combine(path1, path2);
                return combined;
            }
            public partial class ProgramDirectories
            {
                public static string directory = @"DillData\";
                public static string documentspath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
                public static string pathforfiles = PathCombineAndCanonicalize1(documentspath, directory);
                public static string sps = PathCombineAndCanonicalize1(pathforfiles, Constants.sps);
            }
```

With `Constants.sps="text.txt";`
And then I could easily do:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(ProgramDirectories.pathforfiles))
{
     Directory.CreateDirectory(ProgramDirectories.pathforfiles);
}

if(!File.Exists(ProgramDirectories.sps)
{
     File.WriteAllText(ProgramDirectories.sps, "0");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Run your visual studio as administrator and see it works or not.

Comment: I did, I also tried to run the built program with same results.

Comment: Take a look at this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.unauthorizedaccessexception?view=net-5.0

Comment: I did, that's where I got the `file.SetAttribute` but it doesn't work